# How do you transform a list of numbers into a list of three-digit numbers in Racket?

Tags: racket

For example, '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) would transform into '(123 456 789). I tried to find a recursive way of doing this but failed.

Answer (score 1):

For example

```
(define (f lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      null
      (cons (+ (* 100 (car  lst))
               (*  10 (cadr lst))
               (caddr lst))
            (f (cdddr lst)))))
```